# What it take to make such website like this?

Tags: html, web

well i know maybe i ask the wrong question at stackoverflow.

i want to build a website like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URIrsCqrUyk

but what it take to build such website ? framework ? cms ?

i am new to cms , i always hand code website , but this day without cms , website will become hard to manage it.

question

**1. what it take to build website like this ?**

**2. do i need cms ?**

**if do : which one should i try**

**if not : how do such website manage it ?**

thank for sharing your advice , if this post not belong here i will delete after, sorry for trouble and and thank for all.

Comment: you will have alot downvote, but just a hint comment: 1) you can build by hand, or you can build custom cms, or you can use existing cms framework. 2) CMS means, u just build the skeleton of the website, content can be done later after that (by you or others). I didn't watch the whole clip, but seems like this flexitive.com provide a cms for you. 3)Which one: depend on which language/ platform/framework you are prefer? There are many: wordpress, joomla for php, umbraco, sitecore for .net ...

Comment: thanks guys , really appreciate your advice ,i will detele this post soon ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Any good website is the combination of two technology.     Front end and Back end. For frontend you need compulsorily HTML, CSS. For user experience improvement you need Js, Bootstrap, Angular Js etc. For backend you need one of these PHP, Node Js, Python, ASP.Net, JSP etc. And one for database management you can choose from SQL or MongoDb.

2.If your website has a lot of content or if your contents need frequent modification then you should go for CMS.
Apart from this CMS lets you easily organize and maintain your website. CMS lets you add pages, create posts, even maintain user comments. If you don't really require these features then you should go for static hard-coded website.

3. If you are beginner in CMS, I would highly recommend you to use WordPress. WordPress has lot of support, you can have various customizations, you can even perform e-commerce through WordPress. WordPress is easy to use, and easy to setup on the server as its built on PHP and MySql, (two most commonly used backend technology).

Hope I helped you.

Comment: thanks guys , really appreciate your advice ,i will detele this post soon ^^